# unreachable-code-loop-increment warning rules

Tags: c++, clang, std

Consider the following code (clang). It has two identical loops explicitly terminated on the first iteration. One of them throws a warning (an error if -Wpedantic -Werror). The other does not. Trying to understand why. The code can be tested on [Godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/KvjbG5TG4)

```
template <typename K, typename V>
int get(const std::map<K, V>& m) {
        for (const auto& [k, v]: m)
                return v.size(); // No warning
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        std::map<char, std::string>m1 { {'A', "Alex"}, {'B', "Bob"}};
        std::cout << get(m1) << "\n";
        for (const auto& [k, v]: m1)
            return v.size(); // warning: loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed) [-Wunreachable-code-loop-increment] 
        return 0;
}
```

I expect a warning in both cases, although I don't really see a value in this warning. If you are wondering, why - I wanted to implement something like:

```
if (mylist.begin() != mylist.end())
  return mylist.begin();
```

using a loop iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in behaviour seems to be a side-effect of making `get` a template. If you make it a regular function then the warning reappears:

```
int get(const std::map <char, std::string>& m) {
    for (const auto& [k, v]: m)
        return v.size();    // warning: loop will run at most once ...
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7NIJRDmzBEIga78K)

Arguably, this is a clang bug.

I am also a bit puzzled when you say:

> although I don't really see a value in this warning

I don't either, so why did you enable it (since, AFAICT, you have to do so explicitly via `-Wunreachable-code-loop-increment`)?

Comment: I don't enable it in my real-life scenario. It is enabled for me in Android build configuration via -Werror -Wpedantic. I agree that it looks like a clang bug.

Comment: Hmmm, must be a different version of the compiler, I had to enable it explicitly.  Like you, I don't use it in real life.

Comment: Google uses custom-built compilers for Android build. You can enable or disable specific warnings at the build time afaik.